# Quickly computing inversion of a large sparse partial stochastic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, sparse-matrix, graph-theory, approximation

Suppose I have a sparse stochastic matrix $M$ (with thousands or millions of stochastic column vectors), possibly encoding some links in a web graph. Now I split it into two matrices: $D$ containing only the diagonal entries of $M$, and $R$ containing the remaining entries of $M$. What would be a fast way to compute $D(I−R)^{−1}$ (or a good approximation)? Instead of low computational complexity, I'm looking for fast practical performance.

What I actually care about is $D(I−R)^{−1}$ for a continuous stream of vectors $x$'s, though $M$ may also change (both nodes and edges), but less often. Looks similar to PageRank, but still quite different. What would be a fast implementation? - Thanks, Michelle

Comment: Hello Michelle and welcome to Scicomp!  Is the matrix $(I-R)$ well-conditioned, in general?  This can have a big impact on whether approximating its inverse is practical or not.

Comment: What do you know about the entries of $M$? You say they are sparse, so the vectors that make up $M$ are sparse as well. Are the few non-zero entries simply ones, or are they distributed real numbers? Also, are the diagonal entries of $M$ (i.e., the matrix $D$) always nonzero?

Comment: Hello Paul, thanks. I don't know whether $(I-R)$ is technically well-conditioned, but intuitively the answer  varies gradually with gradual changes in $M$.

Comment: Wolfgang, The non-zero entries are usually not 1, but distributed reals (< 1). Some diagonal entries may be zero, but most will be non-zero. Thanks.

Comment: Too bad. I had hoped that the diagonal entries are as sparse as the rest which would mean that $D$ would have only few nonzeros on the diagonal -- making the problem substantially lower-dimensional.

Comment: Given all you say, finding the exact inverse of the matrix may be difficult. Can you elaborate in your question (feel free to edit it) what you intend to do with $D(I-R)^{-1}$? For example, apply it to a few vectors, compute its spectrum, ...?

Comment: Is $(I-R)$ strongly diagonally dominant?

Comment: Is $M$ symmetric?

Comment: In describing the matrix as "partial stochastic" is it meant that the rows are nonnegative and sum to 1?  Or the columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea. How about developing $(I-R)^{-1}$ in a geometric series? It only converges if all the eigenvalues of R are smaller than 1. But if it does then

$D(I-R)^{-1} = D(I+R+R^2+\ldots)$

The problem would be reduced to (hopefully) not many sparse matrix multiplications.